# RoleGroupAOImpl1Client.java:3: error: cannot find symbol import com.shaic.framework.service.org.CreateRoleGroup;

Tags: gradle

> RoleGroupAOImpl1Client.java:3: error: cannot find symbol import
>   com.shaic.framework.service.org.CreateRoleGroup;

I'm getting this error while building, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

your code does not compile, probably because of a missing dependency - the one that has the CreateRoleGroup class. Since it looks like an internal class, you might need to check if it is properly packaged (in a jar) and uploaded to the repository you use.